# Java компиляция в .jar файл

Tags: java

у меня не получается создать исполняемый *.jar файл моей программы в intellij.
Сама проблема: Я создаю через build artifacts *.jar файл, после его запуска ничего не происходит, но есть перейти в директорию с *.jar файлом и прописать в консоль java -jar MyApp.jar, то будет следующая ошибка

```
Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class sample.Main
        java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sample/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
```

У кого была такая проблема, подскажите пожалуйста какие есть варианты решения.

Answer (score 1):

`class file version 60.0` означает, что для компиляции использовался JDK 16, а из консоли запускаете более ранней версией JRE.

Вы это можете проверить запустив из консоли команду `java -version`.

Чтоб исправить настройте переменную PATH, чтобы использовать JRE 16 или выше (место установки можно посмотреть в настройках Intellij: `Platform Settings -> SDKs`.

Comment: Теперь появилась другая ошибка: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: sample/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 60.0